# Unable to remove title field from list definition

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, jsom, sharepoint-addin

I am working with a list integrated into my SharePoint Add-in.  Normally, to remove the title column, I would go into the list settings menu and work with the column that way. The issue is that from the add in, the list settings menu is not available.  I instead went to the XML list definition where I set the title field to required = false.  However, that change is not reflected in the actual list.  When I run the add-in, the list will still not let me add an item without a title value.

Here is the xml for the title field:

```
     <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" />
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the Overwrite attribute?

Answer (score 1):

site settings > advanced settings > allow content management (yes) 
site settings > click on content types (may be list/library name) now click on title column and hide the column.

Comment: The list is contained within a SharePoint add-in, there is no settings menu.  It needs to be done programmatically.